# Google doesn't want to recognize multilingual page

Tags: html, meta-tags, google-search

I have a bilingual website with the language as subdomain structure (https://de.domain.io, https://fr.domain.io, etc.). However, in Google search results, it only displays the results in the Default language, no matter for the location. Google Germany doesn't show me German results, Google France no French.

I use this to tell the Google Robot there are languages

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.domain.io/index.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://en.domain.io/index.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://de.domain.io/index.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://fr.domain.io/index.php">
```

And in the robots.txt this:

```
Sitemap: http://fr.domain.io/sitemap-fr.xml
Sitemap: http://de.domain.io/sitemap-de.xml
Sitemap: http://en.domain.io/sitemap-en.xml
```

Sitmep Structure begins like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
    <loc>https://de.domain.io/</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://en.domain.io/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://fr.domain.io/" />
</url>
```

So what am I doing wrong?!? Since those changes several weeks passed and my website is quite frequently visited by Google etc.